# How to highlight only a specific div onclick in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, onclick, jsx

I am currently creating a sidebar, however I am struggling to highlight a specific `div` on click while keeping the other `div`s un-highlighted. Also, in its initial state, the first menu item should be highlighted already. Please help me out to get rid of this! Below is my code(jsx file)

I have tried using `useState` and vanilla JavaScript. In vanilla nothing is working and when I used `useState` it is creating multiple copies of a single `div`. I just want to highlight a `div` on click while the others remain as it is.

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import "../css/sidebar.css";
import loginuser from "../img/login-user.svg";
import logoutuser from "../img/login-lock.svg";

// let menuitems = document.getElementsByClassName('sidebarmenuitem');
// let prevActive = menuitems[0];
// for(const item of menuitems){
//     item.addEventListener('click', function setActive(event){});
// }
// function setActive(event) {
//     event.target.classList.add("sidebarmenuitemactive");
//     prevActive.classList.remove("sidebarmenuitemactive");
//     prevActive = event.target;
// }

export default function Sidebar() {
  //  const [appState, changeState] = useState({
  //     activeObject: null,
  //     objects: [{ id: 1 }],
  //   });
  //   function toggleActive(index) {
  //     changeState({ ...appState, activeObject: appState.objects[index] });
  //   }
    
  //   function toggleActiveStyles(index) {
  //     if (appState.objects[index] === appState.activeObject) {
  //       return "sidebarmenuitem sidebarmenuitemactive";
  //     } else {
  //       return "sidebarmenuitem";
  //     }
  return (
    <div className="sidebarmenu">
      <p className="menu-name">MENU</p>
      <div className="sidebarmeunitem">
         <img src={loginuser} alt="Pict-CodeLab" className="img" />
         <p className="opt-name">LABS</p>
       </div>
      <div className="sidebarmenuitem">
        <img src={loginuser} alt="Pict-CodeLab" className="img" />
        <p className="opt-name">Assignments</p>
      </div>
      <div
        className="sidebarmenuitem"
        onClick={(e) => e.target.classList.toggle("sidebarmenuitemactive")}
      >
        <img src={loginuser} alt="Pict-CodeLab" className="img" />
        <p className="opt-name">Submitted Codes</p>
      </div>
      <div
        className="sidebarmenuitem"
        onClick={(e) => e.target.classList.toggle("sidebarmenuitemactive")}
      >
        <img src={loginuser} alt="Pict-CodeLab" className="img" />
        <p className="opt-name">Study Material</p>
      </div>
      <p className="menu-name">ACCOUNT</p>
      <div
        className="sidebarmenuitem"
        onClick={(e) => e.target.classList.toggle("sidebarmenuitemactive")}
      >
        <img src={loginuser} alt="Pict-CodeLab" className="img" />
        <p className="opt-name">Profile</p>
      </div>
      <div
        className="sidebarmenuitem"
        onClick={(e) => e.target.classList.toggle("sidebarmenuitemactive")}
      >
        <img src={logoutuser} alt="Pict-CodeLab" className="img" />
        <p className="opt-name">Log Out</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. `onClick` are these menu items meant to change the app route and display a new page? If so you should use a router (as mentioned below). Or are you just trying something using state in the meantime to see how it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a state to keep track of the current active menu:

```
const [active, setActive] = useState('LABS');
```

We also set the initial value to `LABS` to correspond to the arbitrary value we check in the first menu item to make it highlight by default.

In each of the `className` props, we use a conditional to conditionally apply the active class if the `active` state matches the arbitrary string I have decided for the given item:

```
className={`sidebarmeunitem${active === 'LABS' ? ' sidebarmenuitemactive' : ''}`}
```

We make a function that returns an event listener that sets the `active` state variable to the clicked item:

```
const setActiveClick = (id) => () => setActive(id);

// …

onClick={setActiveClick('LABS')}
```

Here it is all together:

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import "../css/sidebar.css";
import loginuser from "../img/login-user.svg";
import logoutuser from "../img/login-lock.svg";

export default function Sidebar() {
  const [active, setActive] = useState('LABS');
  const setActiveClick = (id) => () => setActive(id);

  return (
    <div className="sidebarmenu">
      <p className="menu-name">MENU</p>
      <div
        className={`sidebarmeunitem${active === 'LABS' ? ' sidebarmenuitemactive' : ''}`}
        onClick={setActiveClick('LABS')}
      >
         <img src={loginuser} alt="Pict-CodeLab" className="img" />
         <p className="opt-name">LABS</p>
       </div>
      <div
        className={`sidebarmeunitem${active === 'Assignments' ? ' sidebarmenuitemactive' : ''}`}
        onClick={setActiveClick('Assignments')}
      >
        <img src={loginuser} alt="Pict-CodeLab" className="img" />
        <p className="opt-name">Assignments</p>
      </div>
      <div
        className={`sidebarmeunitem${active === 'Submitted Codes' ? ' sidebarmenuitemactive' : ''}`}
        onClick={setActiveClick('Submitted Codes')}
      >
        <img src={loginuser} alt="Pict-CodeLab" className="img" />
        <p className="opt-name">Submitted Codes</p>
      </div>
      <div
        className={`sidebarmeunitem${active === 'Study Material' ? ' sidebarmenuitemactive' : ''}`}
        onClick={setActiveClick('Study Material')}
      >
        <img src={loginuser} alt="Pict-CodeLab" className="img" />
        <p className="opt-name">Study Material</p>
      </div>
      <p className="menu-name">ACCOUNT</p>
      <div
        className={`sidebarmeunitem${active === 'Profile' ? ' sidebarmenuitemactive' : ''}`}
        onClick={setActiveClick('Profile')}
      >
        <img src={loginuser} alt="Pict-CodeLab" className="img" />
        <p className="opt-name">Profile</p>
      </div>
      <div
        className={`sidebarmeunitem${active === 'Log Out' ? ' sidebarmenuitemactive' : ''}`}
        onClick={setActiveClick('Log Out')}
      >
        <img src={logoutuser} alt="Pict-CodeLab" className="img" />
        <p className="opt-name">Log Out</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Really very grateful for this!!

Comment: I also want to change the image when I click a div can you help me in that also please??

Comment: Use the similar concept above – have a conditional in the `<img>` element's `src` attribute.